# How to open email by x-gm-msgid in Gmail with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm writing an extension which surfaces links to gmail messages. As the UI loads right in Gmail, I should be able to click on one of these links and have Gmail load it (without refreshing). I have "x-gm-msgid" available and theoretically, I should just be able to navigate to "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/[x-gm-msgid]".

I've tried using

```
location.hash = "#inbox/[x-gm-msgid]"
```

I've tried using

```
history.pushState(null, null, "/mail/u/0/#inbox/[x-gm-msgid]")
```

Neither of which works. Gmail just thwarts any attempt to change the URL (unless it is done via user interaction)

Any thoughts on how to get around this restriction?

Comment: Have you tried [chrome.tabs.update](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update)?

Comment: that did it.. awesome! do you want to answer the question so you'd at least get the credit?

Comment: Hey @RuiJ, would you be able to let me know how you were you able to get message ids in the inbox? I'm also writing an extension, and need to be able to open a new email. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[chrome.tabs.update](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update) should work.

> Modifies the properties of a tab. Properties that are not specified in updateProperties are not modified. Note: This function can be used without requesting the 'tabs' permission in the manifest.